# Extracting values from textfield then putting them in a set/arraylist

Tags: java, csv

Why is my `list` empty even after extracting the data from the textfields? Or is there any other way I could take the values from the textfield and append them to a file? Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class AddUser implements ActionListener
 {
   Set<UserBean> list = new HashSet<UserBean>();
   UserBean user = new UserBean();
   Iterator it = list.iterator();
   //Irrelevant code

 private void saveObject()
{
    try
       {
        FileWriter output = new FileWriter("D://names.csv", true);
        if (it.hasNext() == false)
        {
            System.out.println("empty");
        }
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            UserBean current  = (UserBean)it.next();
            output.append(current.getLastName());
            output.append(",");
            output.append(current.getFirstName());
            output.append("\n");
        }
        } catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
    }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
  {
     Object src = ae.getSource();
     if (src == bAdd) 
      { 
        user.setFirstName(tfFirst.getText().trim());
        user.setLastName(tfLast.getText().trim());
        list.add(user);
        saveObject();
       }
```

Comment: Empty catch block = bad idea. How do you know if you're getting exceptions or not?

Comment: Just inserted e.printStackTrace(); into it and it still didn't change the outcome of program, so I guess its not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all your design is horrible.

I see no reason to have the `Iterator` or the `Set` in the first place, since you seem to be saving a single object anyways.

However, add debug statements so that you can be sure that everything is happening as you expect them to.

Comment: Hmm? I thought the line list.add(user); solves the the empty Hashset. Sorry I'm still fairly new to Java.